# How to combat the backslash return character breaking my javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have just realised that if a user enters a '\' into the input field, when I am trying access that value my javascript breaks due to the escape character.

What I wish to know is how I would get around this? I want my users to still be able to input a '\', I have tried using a regEX replace and other similar methods, but my code still breaks regardless (with no error mind you)

JavaScript:

```
var r = document.getElementById('r-box').value;
```

If the above contains a `\`, the code will just freeze.

Comment: Can you post a complete code example please?

Comment: That is my example, I am getting the value of the HTML text field 'r-box'. Do you want the input box HTML too?

Comment: May be you can provide more detailed code preview in jsfiddle or something similar for review.

Comment: All I am doing is using the above line to get the value out of the input field, and then I have an alert that is just alerting it to the screen to debugging.

Comment: The backslash shouldn't normally cause problems in a string. They only have special meaning in Javascript source code, not data. You need to show what you're doing with the `r` variable so we can help you avoid whatever problem you're having.

Comment: Right ok, give me a few minutes

Comment: Do you just alert(r) ? Could you show us what you do with r once its value is set ?

Comment: You're going to need to provide a more complete code snippet because what you have described works fine as proved here: http://jsfiddle.net/ozrevulsion/5kbmqtvh/

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/pepd5sLd/1/ I enter `foo\<RET>bar` and it alerts just fine.

Comment: It seems like it isn't coming from my javascript at all, it is coming from one of my php scripts which I pass the value to. So I think it is SQL not liking the '\' possibly.